# Flask JWT-extended not recognizing access token, only when GET method is used

Tags: python, flask, jwt

**Hi everyone!**

I'm building a website, and I'm stuck with sending a form. My problem is that it sends the `access_token_cookie`, but triggers the `unauthorized_token_callback`. I saw the request and the respone and the request contains the token, but the code pretends like it's not even there.

I can't wrap my head around it, and I need some good tips.

Here is the JWT configuration, the secret keys are not included in this snippet:

```
application.config['JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION'] = ['cookies', 'headers', 'json', 'query_string']
application.config['JWT_COOKIE_SECURE'] = False #! Needs to be changed in production
application.config['JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT'] = True
application.config['JWT_CSRF_CHECK_FORM'] = True
application.config['JWT_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'Strict'
application.config['CSRF_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'csrf_token'
application.config['JWT_ACCESS_CSRF_HEADER_NAME'] = ['X-CSRF-TOKEN-ACCESS', 'X-CSRFToken']
application.config['JWT_CSRF_IN_COOKIES'] = True
```

I'm using a custom decorator, that restricts the user access based on the role of the user:

```
def Xrole_required(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        verify_jwt_in_request()
        role = dth.get_user_by_email(get_jwt_identity()).roles.role_name
        if(role != 'required_role'):
            flash('Xrole required', 'error')
            return Response(render_template('404.html', title='Not Logged In'), 404, mimetype='text/html')
        else:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapper
```

Whenever I remove the decorator, it redirects me with no problem, but using it says that I'm not logged in. I use this decorator on other places and there it works perfectly fine.

The interesting thing is, that this works on every `GET` request, but it does not, on other methods. Here is the form, so you can see it:

```html
<form class="form-control" action="{{ url_for('MyEndpoint_name', show='active') }}" method="POST">
  <div class="row pt-2">
    <label for="desc" class="required">Description</label>
    <input id="desc" name="desc" type="text" required class="shadow-sm rounded border">
  </div>
  <div class="row pt-2">
    <label>Text</label>
    <input type="text" class="shadow-sm rounded border">
  </div>
  <div class="row pt-2">
    <label>Number</label>
    <input type='number' value="0" min="0" class="shadow-sm rounded border">
  </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is the resource that handles the request:

```
class MyResource(Resource):
    
    @Xrole_required
    def post(self, show):
        #here comes the code, this is only for test
        return redirect(url_for('/redirect_page'), 303)
```

Did I make a mistake in here somewhere, or did I miss some crucial part of the documentation?

Please note, that I don't want to use `XMLHttpRequest`, because it would be an overkill, I have a lot of js already and these are simple forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into a CSRF problem. Make sure to set JWT_CSRF_CHECK_FORM to True and include the CRSF token in a hidden field in your form by using https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/#flask_jwt_extended.get_csrf_token